# Web API for iOS opening new browser tabs

Tags: square-connect

When the Square app is calling my web app callback url Safari opens the callback url in a new tab every time I complete a transaction. This results in numerous tabs being opening. Am I doing something wrong or is this to be expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior.

Comment: Any way to auto-close it or something? Is this sub-optimal and it is the only way we can do it in iOS, or is there a use-case for this that I'm not hitting upon?

Comment: not really, for more control, I'd recommend using a native integration.

Comment: Has this gotten any better since then? Is your recommendation still to not use the web-based interface?